# Change layout parameter in bindview in a cursor- Android

Tags: android

I have the following XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="4dip"
    android:paddingRight="4dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="32dip"
        android:layout_height="32dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:src="@drawable/test_imag" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the following bindView in a cursor

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    wrapper = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.background);

    TextView tview2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);

    ImageView imgview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    tview2.setText("Test text");

    if (cursor.getPosition() % 2 == 0) {

        tview2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_left);   

    } else {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        tview2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_right);

        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.imageView1);

        tview2.setLayoutParams(params);

        wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    }

}
```

I'm trying to do a bubble chat with an image, the IF part is fine, the image is on the rght side of the screen, and, the text is to the left of it. 
In the else part I set the gravity to the right and add a rule to set tview2 to the left of the image.

The result of the above made the image go to the right side of the screen but the tview2 has gone, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify params for the **imageview** as well since you've declared it initially in the xml to be relative to the textview.

```
imageparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

The result would be something like this.

```
else {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        imageparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

        imgview.setLayoutParams(imageparams);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        tview2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_right);

        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.imageView1);

        tview2.setLayoutParams(params);

        wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    }
```